# How to tell ember.js and ember-data version from ember-CLI?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Doing `ember -v` only shows ember cli version.

How can you view ember.js version and ember data versions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version of `ember.js` and `ember-data` is determined by your app's dependencies.

`Bower` dependencies are listed in `bower.json` file.

`npm` dependencies are listed in your `package.json` file.

In the command line, you can just use `cat` and `grep` to show you relevant lines.

For example, in the app's directory (same place you use `ember -v`):

```
cat bower.json | grep ember-data
```

That will return any line that matches the text `ember-data`.  It would output something like this:

```
"ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.16.1",
```

Comment: It's just in the bower file. nice. Thank you for the CL commands too!

Comment: note: if you do `cat bower.json | grep ember` you'll get a list of all packages with "ember" in its name.

Comment: Glad that helped.  If you want to learn more about them, you can review their "manual" by using `man <cmd>` (i.e. `man cat` or `man grep`)

Comment: I also suggest that you use the EmberJs plugin for your browser. It's so usefull to debug Ember app in general and it will let you know the versions

Comment: @PascalBoutin agreed - the [Ember Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en) is very useful!

Comment: Be aware your `bower.json` file may contain _softer_ [version restrictions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/496321). In that case you might want to get the actual installed version with something like `bower list` ([docs](http://bower.io/docs/api/#list))

Answer (score 4):

If you're using npm:

```
npm list --depth=0
```

Results in:

```
    <project name> <project location>
    ├── body-parser@1.12.4
    ├── broccoli-asset-rev@0.3.1
    ├── broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler@1.7.0
    ├── broccoli-merge-trees@0.2.1
    ├── ember-breadcrumbs@0.1.6
    ...
```

Comment: And where is ember-data version?