# How do I find the most recently released version of Ember-Data, Ember-CLI, and Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I know how to check what my current version is

[How to tell ember.js and ember-data version from ember-CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912389/how-to-tell-ember-js-and-ember-data-version-from-ember-cli)

But if I want to check which version I'm on from Ember-CLI, what is the best way to do this? I know I can google it but it would be nice if I could get the latest version straight from my command-prompt.

Comment: Do you want to check the current version, or find the latest version?

Comment: I want to know the most recently released version (not the one I currently have installed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ember](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/releases), [ember-cli](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases), and [ember-data](https://github.com/emberjs/data/releases) all keep their releases in sync. You can check what the latest release is in your terminal by using [npm-view](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view)

```
npm view ember-cli version
npm view ember-data version
```

But my favorite way is to just check the blog, it always has the latest releases with some helpful notes. https://emberjs.com/blog/

Comment: Just did. Thank you!